# Cannot create ODBC datasource using SQL Native Client

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-native-client

I have SQL Server 2005 and some databases created on system A. Then I had to create System B by cloning system A. I made all the necessary changes to ip and hostname and respective changes to sql server configurations.

Earlier I had created an ODBC data source on system C to connect to sql server on system A and everything worked fine.
After cloning, I tried to modify the odbc data source to connect to sql server on system B. But I am getting below error

```
Connection failed:
SQLState: '08001'
SQL Server Error: 53
[Microsoft][SQL Native Client]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].
Connection failed:
SQLState: 'HYT00'
SQL Server Error: 0
[Microsoft][SQL Native Client]Login timeout reached.
Connection failed:
SQLState: '08001'
SQL Server Error: 53
[Microsoft][SQL Native Client]An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server. When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote connections.
```

All the 3 systems are on same network.
The strange thing is that I am getting this error only while creating data source from system C. I can create data source on system A to SQL Server on system B. It seems that system C has problems, but in that case I should not be able to create data source on system C to connect to system A whereas I am able to.

Data source on system C to sql server on system A : Success
Data source on system A to sql server on system B : Success
Data source on system C to sql server on system B : Failure

Can someone point me to what could be causing this?

Comment: ...have you checked that the SQL Server for system C allows remote connections?

Comment: there are no incoming connections to system C so will that matter? Moreover system C can connect to system B successfully.

Comment: I followed the instructions in http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2102.how-to-troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine.aspx and found that I cannot telnet to port 1433 of system B from system C Seems that system C has blocked it. Confirming it with the system administrator of sys C.